# Using header() with wordpress enqueue

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, content-type

I'm basically trying to make my js and css files dynamic. I've tried a few different ways of doing this and it isn't seeming to work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

functions.php

```
function fnp_add_js() {
    //I've tried fnp_jquery.js.php fnp_jquery.php and fnp_jquery.js
    wp_register_script( 'fnp_jquery', plugins_url( 'fnp_jquery.js.php', __FILE__ ));

    wp_enqueue_script('fnp_jquery');
}
```

base.php

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fnp_add_js');
```

jquery.js 
(I've tried fnp_jquery.js.php fnp_jquery.php and fnp_jquery.js)

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/javascript');

//I've also tried surrounding $(document).ready(function() {}  with echo ''; 
?>

$(document).ready(function() {
   //Javascript here
});
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly, your script doesn't get enqued, it doesn't get served correctly?

Comment: I believe it is getting enqueued, as the source shows the <script..></script> tag, however I dont think that it is reading the javascript correctly.

Comment: It was working fine before I tried to make the jquery.js file into a php file so that I could use php variables in the javascript

Comment: Ok, fireup firebug or whatever console you are working with in your browser (usually F12) and look in the network tab if the header is really pushing out text/javascript and if the content is really there

Comment: I couldn't find what you were talking about it firebug, however when I got to the script panel, it does not show the file loaded whereas other javascript files are.

Comment: Go into the network tab, it shows all resources loaded

Comment: I believe it is loaded.  It shows "GET fnp_jquery.js.php?ver=3.31"

Comment: Ok, and the file is of type text/javascript in the network panel? Click the file and check the "response" header to see if the content-type is right!

Comment: What have you tried to put in your javascvript file to make sure it doesn'T work, cause this all looks valid at this point

Comment: Oh, I looked in the "header" header! I found the "response" header and noticed there was an error, corrected this and it worked!

Comment: I pasted my solution down there, please flag it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your problem exactly, your script doesn't get enqued, it doesn't get served correctly?

Fireup firebug or whatever console you are working with in your browser (usually F12) and look in the network tab if the header is really pushing out text/javascript and if the content is really there.